# Backbone: Events vs Direct calls vs [your solution] for generic library usage

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

We've been tasked to add some GTM tracking to a complex backbone app and thinking about the various ways we can implement this.

To avoid implementation specific logic throughout the app we've developed a small library that will allow us to pass it an object of parameters and it will handle the construction of the tracking object and pushing it to the dataLayer. Our thinking is that if, in the future, our client wants to change the tracking provider, we just need to swap out the library.

The question is how to handle this. My colleague and I have each come up with a possible solution:

**Listening and reacting to events from the router.**

The router listens for tracking events on the current view and calls out to the tracking library. 
Components trigger events which are passed (again via more events) up to the router.

Pros:

- Keeps the components decoupled (if a component is re-used in a future project which has no tracking we don't *need* to make any changes, events will silently trigger and be ignored)
- If the tracking provider is changed in the future, we can just swap out the library and the calls to it in the router

Cons:

- With deeply nested components needing to initiate tracking, events will be a PITA and very messy to set up and actually follow what's going on

**Calling the library directly from the components initiating the tracking**

The components import a reference to the library and when an event occurs that needs to be tracked, the component directly calls the tracking library

Pros:

- Simpler to set up and follow what's going on

Cons:

- Components have an extra dependency, making them a little more coupled.

Are there any other ways of handling this that we should be aware of? We've considered a global event system (if that's possible?)

Comment: This would be better asked on [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) I think.

Comment: @EmileBergeron when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)